# saving visits to doctors, way how to save in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am wondering how to save in the database of doctors appointments  (is their 3).

I thinking about create calendar-model, in this model every doctor will have his own document which looks like:

```
Calendar-model {
    doctorID : String,
    doctor: String,
calendar : [{
    Day [{
        yyyy : Number,
        mm : Number, 
        dd : Number,
            Time: [{
                h : Number,
                m : Number,
                patient : String,
                patientID : String
            }]
    }]
 }]
}
```

the thought is every day the thought is every day can be saved 8 visits and to every visit will be saved name and id a patient.

Can I do it this way, or would you advise me to do something completely different??

Thanks

Comment: Try to model it how you are using it, are you querying the data on a day by day basis?

Comment: I don't understand, I want to know Is it a good solution to use arrays in the database

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use arrays and embedded documents